# Including Puppetlabs repo when provisioning Ubuntu client with Foreman

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, provisioning-profile, apt-get, theforeman

Due to my manifests requiring the latest version of factor, all provisioned machines has to undergo a manual in-between step after OS installation of adding the puppetlabs repo and upgrading facter.

Even specifying that all subclasses require the installation, it aborts the entire manifest. All 100% after installing latest facter though.

Any way to have the puppetlabs repo being part of the provisioning process?
I though uncommenting this line:
`<% if puppet_enabled && @host.params['enable-puppetlabs-repo'] &&     @host.params['enable-puppetlabs-repo'] == 'true' -%>`
would do the trick, but no.

Also, the variables in the provisioning template (like hte enable-puppetlabs-repo above), where are they set?

Answer (score 0):

This gets applied in foreman's host groups.  add it as a parameter to your hostgroup config in the UI and should work.